# Jasper - Oracle - query result table is repeated

Tags: oracle, jasper-reports, rownum

I cannot get a complex query for a table in jasper to return a single table. It repeats the resultant table the same number of times as the number of rows that are returned. With a simple query I could overcome this by using `where rownum<=1`.

With the following query, 'where rownum<=1' helps nothing (it gives me only one row as a result when there should be many and I still have multiple repeated tables):

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4, column5 from the_table
WHERE (column1 like CONCAT ($P{column1},'%'))
AND (column2 like CONCAT ($P{column2},'%'))
AND (column3 like CONCAT ($P{column3},'%'))
AND (column4 like CONCAT ($P{column4},'%'))
AND (column5 like CONCAT ($P{column5},'%'))
AND rownum<=1
ORDER BY column4 DESC
```

I'd like only one table to be returned in my Jasper report - not as many as there are rows in the table.

Comment: What do you actually need? If the 'where rownum<=1.' can solve, what more do you want? Kindly explain more or add printscreen.

Comment: 'where rownum<=1' only helped when my select statement was relatively simple. i'll add my current select statement into my question. somehow with this one i get as many table as there are rows...

Comment: using 'where rownum<=1'  actually means you're trimming down your result to only one row, so no matter how much conditions there are in  your query the result would be only one records.

Comment: however if you would like to have all the records that satisfies your query then why'dd you have to put the 'where rownum<=1' ?Correct me if im wrong as per my understanding to your case, you want to display the all the records from your query in a single table right? then the ' where rownum<=1' definitely won't do. I suggest let us see your jrxml. The conflict most possibly be there.

Comment: yes I agree it sounds wrong... I thought so myself when I first implemented this solution. As I say, it works with a simple select query but with this one it doesn't. 
So, without this rownum thing, I do get all the results. But instead of having them display in only one table, that same correct table repeats. This is what I'm trying to solve - I only want one table to display.

Comment: The inspiration for 'rownum<=1' came from the 'limit' function in mysql which solves this problem. Even though the idea doesn't immediately make much sense to me again...

Comment: have you tried this 'isPrintRepeatedValues="false" ' for your table? though not very sure if this will be the solution ;)

Comment: I assume that's a property somewhere although I cannot find it... where do I set that?

Comment: in property of your table, or wait do you actually create a table or just made your text fields arranged as a table? mind if we can see some part of your code so to have a clear understanding in your current work?

Comment: I have an actual table... I can't find this property :( i'm in ireport... i could send you my jrxml but i'd have to deal with it a bit first - might take some time.

Comment: in the designer you can see it in the properties, it is in default 'check' just uncheck it. hope this helps. good luck.

Comment: Sorry - found it. Unchecked it but no change :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AND rownum<=1` is correct.
It must just be added in the main query - not a sub-dataset. :)